# python - generate combinations (itertools)?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-itertools

Can someone please give me a hint to put me on the right path.

I need to write Python code to come up with all the combinations to solve the following:
I need to generate all possible letter combinations. There will always be 6 letters. However only certain letters can be in each position e.g.

- The first character can only be the letters a or t (2 possibilities)
- The second character can be a, t or c (3 possibilities)
- The third character can be g or t (2 possibilities)
- The fourth character can be a, t, c or g (4 possibilities)
- The fifth character can be c, g or t (3 possibilities)
- The sixth character can b a, or t (2 possibilities)

I think I should use Python itertools but all examples I have looked at have a fixed number of options available (in my case letters) for each position whereas for this the letters available will vary per position.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `itertools.product('at', 'atc', 'gt', ...)`?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this task

You need to create a list of lists for each possible value:

```
import itertools

l = [
        ['a','t'],
        ['a','t','c'],
        ['g','t'],
        ['a','t','c','g'],
        ['c','g','t'],
        ['a','t']
    ]

for out in itertools.product(*l):
    print out;
```

This outputs 288 items. A small sample is:

```
('t', 't', 't', 'g', 'g', 't')
('t', 't', 't', 'g', 't', 'a')
('t', 't', 't', 'g', 't', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'c', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'g', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 't', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'a', 't', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 'c', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 'c', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 'g', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 'g', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 't', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 't', 't', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'c', 'c', 'a')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'c', 'c', 't')
('t', 'c', 'g', 'c', 'g', 'a')
```

---

As jonsharpe points out in the the comment you can also have a single list of the valid strings (replacing the `l` variable from above with this):

```
l = ['at','atc','gt','atcg','cgt','at']
```

Comment: You can just have a list of strings `['at', 'atc', ...]`

Comment: Super. Thanks Andy. That's exactly what I need.